# PHP code to print out page title and meta description?

Tags: php, title, meta

I need a php code to print Page Title and/or Meta Description.

They are already there, but I need it to put a dynamic Title in the twitter sharing link...

```
For example: This is Twitter sharing link which works :
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=Hello+World&url=<?php echo curPageURL();?>"

I want to include there Page Title/ or Meta Description 
so the link would look like :
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=<?php /// ?>&url=<?php echo curPageURL();?>"
```

Titles/Meta descriptions are generated by Forum and plugin.

Comment: What have you done for that?

Comment: you can use $location = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];  to get server path and $location = substr(strrchr($location, "="), 1) to get page name

Comment: I can't show a code, stackoverflow is not displaying...

Comment: Where is the actual page title coming from? what generates it? are you using a cms?

Comment: It's a forum and plugin that generates Titles...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a solution actually :)

If I could vote , I would vote for Ben with a question

> Where is the actual page title coming from? what generates it? are you using a cms? – Ben

Comment: But still - if you have a General Solution - I'd like to hear, I mean independently of CMS